# How to choose features to condition on in DiD causal model?

Tags: causality, generalized-did

I’m looking at CausalPy documentation and the algorithm of interest ir Difference in Differences. I see that they build two different models.

In general, how should one select the features and/or interactions to condition on in a DiD model?

https://causalpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/did_pymc_banks.html